# How can I adjust the x axis to show price as an integer?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QT70.png)

I'm trying to get my graphs to work but the x axis is in decimal points. How can I read or adjust this?

Comment: `ax = sns.kdeplot(...)` and `ax.ticklabel_format(axis='x', style='plain')`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. After checking out the linked duplicate, please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236, and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. We aren't interested in your background or experience; we *are* interested in a *clear, specific* question. "How can I change the x-axis to show <...> instead of <...>?" qualifies. "Can someone help me out?" does not. Also, it is usually best to show at least some relevant code, and indicate [what you tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).